# Using Codeception what do I use for a Page Object when testing REST APIs

Tags: design-patterns, bdd, pageobjects, codeception

I'm using Codeception to create api tests for some REST API's. I'm finding that the Page Objects are really helpful in writing my tests but should I be using another Codeception object?

For example, I'm putting User information (first name, last name, user ID ...) into a UsersPage Page Object class but it is bothering me that it is named Users **Page** when it is not representing a page. Is there another Codeception Object I should be using to represent reusable information I'm using in the tests?

Answer (score 1):

I think your concern is reasonable, it's not good to use page object in your case here;

From your description, you want to pass information (namely data/fixture) to your test cases, so I would choose to use fixtures, namely test data, which goes into the `_data` folder in codeception, load them before tests run.

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer